# Looping through a postgres table and returning the wekid

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a requirement to loop through a table having all the reporting periods right from 2010.
I need to loop through this table so that i when I pass the date string, it takes at and compares it if it is less than the reporting_periods_o and returns back the reporting_period_string.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rpt.reportingperiods(IN v_date text)
 RETURNS SETOF text AS
 $BODY$
 DECLARE

v_in_date INT := CAST(v_date AS INT);
i     INT;
v_sk       INT;

BEGIN
For i IN SELECT rpt_sk FROM rpt.REPORTING_PERIODS LOOP 
    SELECT rpt_sk INTO v_sk FROM rpt.REPORTING_PERIODS  where rpt_sk = i;
    IF v_in_date <= (SELECT reporting_periods_o FROM rpt.REPORTING_PERIODS
               WHERE rpt_sk = i) 
    THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT MIN(reporting_periods)reporting_periods FROM rpt.REPORTING_PERIODS WHERE rpt_sk =  v_sk AND CAST(reporting_periods AS DATE) > CAST(now() AS DATE);
    END IF;
END LOOP;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100
ROWS 1000;
```

My reporting periods has three fields:

```
 rpt_sk, reporting_periods, reporting_periods_o
  1          2014-03-08          20140308
```

I have implemented a function but when I execute I am getting multiple records, I need to be able to get back one record.

Comment: What's a `wekid`? Get back only one record? Please define which. Add the table definition - what you get with `\d tbl` in psql. Your Postgres version? Don't start your question with `I have a requirement to loop ...` Start by telling *what* you actually need, not *how* you tried to achieve it. For starters, looping is a measure of last resort. SQL is a declarative language, plpgsql is just the glue for SQL. There is most probably a more or less simple query to get this done ...

Comment: You're accepting a text field as an argument called `v_date` and then converting it to an integer immediately. I don't understand why you're not just using `date` or `timestamp` data types. Other than that I agree with @ErwinBrandstetter.

Comment: Wekid is the reporting period in the retail industry. The table definition is CREATE TABLE rpt.reporting_periods
(
  rpt_sk serial NOT NULL,
  reporting_periods text,
  reporting_periods_o integer,
  CONSTRAINT reporting_periods_pk PRIMARY KEY (rpt_sk )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
); This is what is in my table SELECT T.REPORTING_PERIODS, CAST(REPLACE(REPORTING_PERIODS,'-','') AS INT)REPORTING_PERIODS_O
FROM
(
SELECT '2014-01-04' REPORTING_PERIODS
UNION 

UNION 
SELECT '2014-02-01'
UNION 
SELECT '2014-02-08'
UNION 
SELECT '2014-02-15'
UNION 
SELECT '2014-10-25'

Comment: To explain further, I have all the reporting periods being used stored in a table, all the reporting periods end on a saturday of every week. For me to be able derive the weekid from dates I have  foreaxmple all the data with dates from 2014-04-21 to 2014-04-25 in a week, if those dates are less than or equal 2014-04-25 they should have 2014-04-25 as the weekid.

Comment: I think the "weekid" can be obtained form date using the following query:
`select (date_trunc('week', '2014-04-21'::date) + interval '4 days')::date::text;`
The expression converts any date in the week to last Monday's date, then adds 4 days to advance to Friday (add 5 for Saturday). The result is converted to date and then to string to drop hours from the result./

Comment: @user3416060: Please do not post essential details in the comments. That's *very* hard to read. Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23301082/edit) button left under the question to update the question itself. Also, please clarify: `wekid` or `weekid`? And don't forget the table definition as explained in my first comment. It is essential.

Comment: Are you going to edit your question or should we go ahead an delete it?