# Nesting Case Statements in postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have this python function I am trying to convert into sql in Postgresql 9.2.

```
def calc_open_order(xOrder):
    temp_row = xOrder.so_reportL[0]
    open_closed_status = 'OPEN'
    order_status = temp_row[3]
    if order_status == 'FAILED':
        open_closed_status = 'CLOSED'
    elif order_status == 'REMOVED':
        open_closed_status = 'CLOSED'
    elif order_status == 'NO_PENDING_ACTION':
        open_closed_status = 'CLOSED'
    elif order_status == 'PENDING_REMOVED':
        open_closed_status = 'CLOSED'
    else:
        # check the shipping group status
        any_open_sg = False
        for sd_row in xOrder.so_reportL:
            if sd_row[45] == 'PENDING_SHIPMENT':
                any_open_sg = True
            elif sd_row[45] == 'PROCESSING':
                any_open_sg = True
            elif sd_row[45] == 'INITIAL':
                any_open_sg = True
            elif sd_row[45] == 'PENDING_MERCHANT_ACTION':
                any_open_sg = True
        if any_open_sg == False:
            open_closed_status = 'CLOSED'
    #
    if open_closed_status == 'CLOSED':
        ord_open_ind = 'False'
    else:
        ord_open_ind = 'True'
    return ord_open_ind,
```

I have converted this logic into sql using a case statment:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (
         CASE WHEN CASE WHEN ord_status IN ('FAILED','REMOVED','NO_PENDING_ACTION', 'NO_PEDNING_ACTION', 'PENDING_REMOVED') THEN 'CLOSED'
                        WHEN ord_status NOT IN ('FAILED','REMOVED','NO_PENDING_ACTION', 'NO_PEDNING_ACTION', 'PENDING_REMOVED') THEN 'OPEN'
                        WHEN SHIPPING_STATUS IN ('PENDING_SHIPMENT','PROCESSING','INITIAL','PENDING_MERCHANT_ACTION') THEN 'True'
                        ELSE 'False' END = 'False' THEN 'CLOSED' AS OPEN_ORDER_IND
```

Please note that sd_row[45] is the same as the Shipping_status field.
Is my case statement right?

Comment: why would you do this... surely python `if/else` is just as fast as postgres case ... and amillion times mroe readable ... (although you could certainly clean up that python a little)

Comment: I did not write the python script, i am just converting the logic in the python script into sql using a case statement.

Comment: Please fix the format of your question. I tried, but it's not clear what's what. Also please respond to [pending requests to your previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301082/looping-through-a-postgres-table-and-returning-the-wekid) before starting new ones.

Comment: Well, the SQL you posted is obvious syntactical nonsense. It's clear you never tested ...

Comment: I did test it but I just wanted to make sure that I was doing the right thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be (untested):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ord_status IN ('FAILED','REMOVED','NO_PENDING_ACTION', 'PENDING_REMOVED')
              OR shipping_status NOT IN ('PENDING_SHIPMENT','PROCESSING','INITIAL','PENDING_MERCHANT_ACTION')
            THEN 'False'::text
            ELSE 'True' END AS ord_open_ind
```

The return type should probably better be [`boolean`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-boolean.html), but that's not in your question.

Comment: @user3416060: Your suggested edit was rejected, but you are still right. I applied it.